# Determine if Google Analytics is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to track specific actions using Google Analytics, but I don't want to track them locally when I'm developing the site.  Locally I don't load Google Analytics, so I'm trying to only enable the tracking if GA is loaded.  When I added the condition shown below it stopped tracking actions, any thoughts on why?

```
  if (typeof _qag != "undefined") {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', ucfirst(Site.page.tabs.main.getSelected().attr('data-siteName'))+' Tab', 'Clicked deal header', ucfirst(Site.page.tabs.getSelected().attr('data-siteName'))]);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't it be "_gaq" instead of "_qag" on your if?
That way it's always false.